# Recursion : not printing all permutations of a string. Missing logic?

Tags: java, recursion

Not printing all the permutations and program exits. Recursion is stopped by printing only three permutations;  Given String is "ABCD"

```
    private static void myPermutations( String permutation,
                                    String str )
{
    if( str.length() == 0 )
        System.out.println( " -- >" + permutation );

    for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
    {
        permutation = permutation + str.charAt( i );
        str = str.substring( 0, i ) + str.substring( i + 1 );
        myPermutations( permutation, str );
    }

}
```

But this works. Whats the difference ?

```
private static void printPermutations( String candidate,
                                       String remaining )
{
    if( remaining.length() == 0 )
        System.out.println( "--> " + candidate );

    for( int i = 0; i < remaining.length(); i++ )
    {
        String newcandidate = candidate + remaining.charAt( i );
        String newremaining = remaining.substring( 0, i ) + remaining.substring( i + 1 );
        printPermutations( newcandidate, newremaining );
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first one, you modify `permutation` and `str` in the `for` loop. In the 2nd one you do not. You use temporary values instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, you are modifying the variable used to control loop inside the loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
{
    ...
    str = str.substring( 0, i ) + str.substring( i + 1 );
    ...
}
```

str variable is in the for loop condition. It is also modified inside the loop.